# Send HTML form attachment in email

Tags: php

I know there are many questions/answers to this on here as well as all over Google, and I've looked through many but can't seem to find a solution that works for me, tried all but failed. Feel free to rate negative if you think I haven't searched hard enough.

I'm new to PHP, and this is the first time I've needed to use file attachments so it's foreign to me.

Can someone help?

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
if ($_POST["application-submit"]) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $height = $_POST['height'];
    $weight = $_POST['weight'];
    $picture = $_POST['picture'];
    $to = 'models@swoleinc.com'; 
    $subject = 'Swole Inc Application';

    $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?:
    getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
    getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?:
    getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
    getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?:
    getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

    $body ="Name: $name\n\n
    E-Mail: $email\n\n 
    Age: $age\n\n 
    Height: $height\n\n
    Weight: $weight\n\n
    Picture: $picture\n\n
    IP Address: $ip";

    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = '^ You forgot your name!';
    }

    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = '^ We need a valid email.';
    }

    if (!$_POST['age']) {
        $errAge = '^ How old are you?';
    }

    if (!$_POST['height']) {
        $errHeight = '^ Tell us how tall you are.';
    }

    if (!$_POST['weight']) {
        $errWeight = '^ We promise we won\'t laugh!';
    }

    if (!$_POST['picture']) {
        $errPicture = '^ Show us your physique!';
    }

    if (!$errName && !$errAge && !$errHeight && !$errWeight && !$errEmail && !$errPicture) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body)) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thanks for applying! If you fit our current needs, we\'ll be in touch soon!</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry, something\'s broken. If the problem persists, email models@swoleinc.com instead.</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<?php include('apply.php'); ?>
              <form action="#apply" method="post" id="apply" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <i class="text-muted">All fields are required.</i><p style="margin-bottom: 15px"></p>
                </div>

                <div class="group">      
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
                  <span class="highlight"></span>
                  <span class="bar"></span>
                  <?php echo "<p class='alert-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
                  <label>Name</label>
                </div>

                <div class="group">      
                  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
                  <span class="highlight"></span>
                  <span class="bar"></span>
                  <?php echo "<p class='alert-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
                  <label>Email</label>
                </div>

                <div class="group">      
                  <input type="text" class="extra" name="age" id="age" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['age']); ?>">
                  <span class="highlight"></span>
                  <span class="bar"></span>
                  <?php echo "<p class='alert-danger'>$errAge</p>";?>
                  <label>Age</label>
                </div>

                <div class="group">      
                  <input type="text" class="extra" name="height" id="height" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['height']); ?>">
                  <span class="highlight"></span>
                  <span class="bar"></span>
                  <?php echo "<p class='alert-danger'>$errHeight</p>";?>
                  <label>Height</label>
                </div>

                <div class="group">      
                  <input type="text" class="extra" name="weight" id="weight" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['weight']); ?>">
                  <span class="highlight"></span>
                  <span class="bar"></span>
                  <?php echo "<p class='alert-danger'>$errWeight</p>";?>
                  <label>Weight</label>
                </div>  

                <div class="group">
                    <input type="file" name="picture" allow="images/*" style="border-bottom: 0; padding: 0" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['picture']); ?>">
                    <?php echo "<p class='alert-danger'>$errPicture</p>";?>
                </div>

                <div class="group">
                    <?php echo $result; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="group">
                    <input id="application-submit" type="submit" name="application-submit" class="btn-apply text-center" value="I have what it takes!" style="display: block; padding: 20px 30px">
                </div>
              </form>
```

Feel free to view the live version: [Swole Inc](https://www.swoleinc.com/)

As you will see, the image won't send right now which obviously won't let the form submit because it'll give the error message.

EDIT:

This was one of the variations I tried:

```
<?php
if ($_POST["application-submit"]) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $height = $_POST['height'];
    $weight = $_POST['weight'];
    $picture = $_POST['picture'];
    $to = 'models@swoleinc.com'; 
    $subject = 'Swole Inc Application';

    $file = $path . "/" . $filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

    $separator = md5(time());

    $eol = PHP_EOL;

    $headers = "From: name <models@swoleinc.com>" . $eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
    $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol . $eol;

    $headers .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol . $eol;
    $headers .= $message . $eol . $eol;

    $headers .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol . $eol;
    $headers .= $content . $eol . $eol;
    $headers .= "--" . $separator . "--";

    $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?:
    getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
    getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?:
    getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
    getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?:
    getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

    $body ="Name: $name\n\n
    E-Mail: $email\n\n 
    Age: $age\n\n 
    Height: $height\n\n
    Weight: $weight\n\n
    Picture: $picture\n\n
    IP Address: $ip";

    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = '^ You forgot your name!';
    }

    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = '^ We need a valid email.';
    }

    if (!$_POST['age']) {
        $errAge = '^ How old are you?';
    }

    if (!$_POST['height']) {
        $errHeight = '^ Tell us how tall you are.';
    }

    if (!$_POST['weight']) {
        $errWeight = '^ We promise we won\'t laugh!';
    }

    if (!$_POST['picture']) {
        $errPicture = '^ Show us your physique!';
    }

    if (!$errName && !$errAge && !$errHeight && !$errWeight && !$errEmail && !$errPicture) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thanks for applying! If you fit our current needs, we\'ll be in touch soon!</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry, something\'s broken. If the problem persists, email models@swoleinc.com instead.</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Files posted in forms, ie *<input type="file" name="picture".../>*, are in *$_FILES* - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php not *$_POST* as you try to access in *if (!$_POST['picture']) {*

Comment: You need a bit of code that handles the file, `!$_POST['picture']` is not currently suffice to determine if the uploaded image has been handled correctly. Have you tried any image upload code? Your question is in fact a little vague, the only question being in the title, I suggest you upload this file to your server, then attach it in an email to notify yourself/admin of the request.

Comment: I actually have tried about 4 different variations of image upload code, none doing any help. The POST picture that I have was meant to be erased, sorry for that misunderstanding.

Comment: post one version of what you attempted and we can help you debug it, cant debug fresh air

Comment: If you have tried *about 4 different variations of image upload code*, it would be helpful if you showed at least one variation attempt, as your current question screams of *Give free code!*. We are here to help, but would like to see your attempt first.

Comment: One variation of image upload code will be all that you need, getting it working is most likely your issue. Add some upload code, as simple as you can find it then post again if you have a problem. `if ($_FILES["picture"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["picture"]["error"] . "<br />";
    } else {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["picture"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["picture"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["picture"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"];
    }`

Comment: Made an edit showing one of the 4 methods I tried that failed me (I'm certain I'm just doing something wrong but can't find it, again I'm very new to PHP as a whole, let alone sending file attachments).